# No acceptable module com.google.android.gms.providerinstaller.dynamite found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm having a problem.

After Firebase and FlutterFire configuration, I'm having a lot of warnings and erros:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WSQh.png)

I already add network permissions to the AndroidManifest, already elevate the minSdk to 21 and using google-services 4.3.15 and added multiDexEnabled true to the default config on gradle.

My main function
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV7UQ.png)

The errors occurs when I try to use:

```
final db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('mydocs');
db.get().then((value) => print(value.docs));
```

I'm using Flutter 3.10.5 and Dart 3.0.5

Any tip?

I'm expecting see no warnings and errors